# PrimeFaces validating group of inputs

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces and JSF. I have an optional address fields. If user fills any one of the fields (eg zip or name) then all other fields are required. What is best way to do this validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a postValidate event to validate multiple fields , like

```
<f:event listener="#{bean.validationMethod}" type="postValidate" />
<h:panelGroup id="xyz" rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
  <h:message for="myform"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="myform">
 .......
<h:panelGroup>
```

this should fire before model updates and you can get the new value for different component with

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
UIComponent components = event.getComponent();
UIInput param1 = (UIInput) components.findComponent("param1");
UIInput param2 = (UIInput) components.findComponent("param2");
```

If the validation fails , call the F`acesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed()` and add message for myform .

If you are not using a custom validation and just want to make sure other inputs are added when a particular input is filled then I would suggest using *Omnifaces validateAllOrNone*,

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateAllOrNone